# How to show a username + column_time using an SQLite cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, database-cursor

Right now, I'm confused with the SQLite cursor. Before I made it using the recyclerview method, but in my code it uses a cursor.
I can't show the column, and I'm confused what should I add.

In my case I have *table_user* and *table_timer*.
Inside *table_user*, it has COLUMN_USERNAME, and inside the table timer, it has COLUMN_TIMER_RESULT_FOR_4.
If I want to call both of them, how do I do it?

Leaderboard

```
private void populateUsernamesList(){
    // Create a list of strings
    List<String> userStrings = new ArrayList<String>(0);
    usernames = userList.getAllUsers();

    // Enters all the usernames to the array
    for(int i = 0; i<usernames.size(); i++){
        userStrings.add(usernames.get(i).toString());
    }

    // Enters them to array adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_element, userStrings);
    usernamesListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

UserList

```
public UserList(Context c) {
    userList = new ArrayList<User>(0);
    userDataSource = new UserDAO(c);
    userDataSource.open();
}

//Methods fot userList interact with the userDAo to get, create, check, delete and return All users
public User getUser(int userID){
    return userDataSource.getUserById(userID);
}

public boolean createUser(User u){
    return userDataSource.createUser(u);
}

public boolean checkUsername(String u){
    return userDataSource.checkUsername(u);
}

public Boolean deleteUser(User u){
  return  userDataSource.deleteUser(u);
}

public Boolean deleteResults(User u){ return userDataSource.deleteResults(u); }

public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    userList = userDataSource.getAllUsers();
    return userList;
}
```

User

```
public User(int usernameId, String username, Integer level4) {
    this.usernameId = usernameId;
    this.username = username;
    //this.level4 = level4;
}

//toString method for printing the contents of a class object
@Override
public String toString() {
    return username ;
}

//
//public int getLevel4() {return level4    ;}

// Getters and setters
public int getUsernameId() {
    return usernameId;
}

public void setUsernameId(int usernameId) {
    this.usernameId = usernameId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

UserDAO

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(0);

    // Get data from the db
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_USERS, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    // Loop through the cursor(result set) and create new usernames objects
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        User user = cursorToUser(cursor);
        userList.add(user);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return userList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To call both the `COLUMN_USERNAME` from `table_user` and `COLUMN_TIMER_RESULT_FOR_4` from `table_timer`, you'll need to modify the `getAllUsers` method in the `UserDAO` class to retrieve the necessary data from both tables and construct the `User` objects accordingly. Here's how you can achieve it:

1. Update the `User` class to include the `COLUMN_TIMER_RESULT_FOR_4` field:

```java
public class User {
    // Other fields
    private int timerResultFor4;

    public User(int usernameId, String username, int timerResultFor4) {
        this.usernameId = usernameId;
        this.username = username;
        this.timerResultFor4 = timerResultFor4;
    }

    // Other methods and getters/setters
    // ...

    public int getTimerResultFor4() {
        return timerResultFor4;
    }

    public void setTimerResultFor4(int timerResultFor4) {
        this.timerResultFor4 = timerResultFor4;
    }
}
```

2. Modify the `UserDAO` class to join the two tables and retrieve the required data:

```java
public class UserDAO {
    // Other methods and variables
    // ...

    // Modified getAllUsers method with JOIN query
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Create the SQL query with a JOIN to fetch data from both tables
        String query = "SELECT u." + COLUMN_USERNAME + ", t." + COLUMN_TIMER_RESULT_FOR_4 +
                " FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " u " +
                " LEFT JOIN " + TABLE_TIMER + " t ON u." + COLUMN_USERNAME + " = t." + COLUMN_USERNAME;

        // Execute the query and get the cursor
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);

        // Loop through the cursor(result set) and create new User objects
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME));
            int timerResultFor4 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TIMER_RESULT_FOR_4));

            User user = new User(-1, username, timerResultFor4);
            userList.add(user);
        }

        cursor.close();
        return userList;
    }
}
```

With these changes, the `getAllUsers` method will return a list of `User` objects, each containing the `COLUMN_USERNAME` from `table_user` and the corresponding `COLUMN_TIMER_RESULT_FOR_4` from `table_timer`. Please note that you may need to adjust the column names and other parts of the code based on your specific table and column names.

Comment: can you justify code in userDAO
private String[] allColumns = {
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_USERNAME,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TIMER_RESULT_FOR_4};

Comment: i get an error https://ibb.co/kxJhVv5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Vivek Kumar Sahani!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.